# show 20 years back years in datepicker for DOB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker for DOB,I need to show 22 years back years with compairing to the current year.When i use yearrange is not  working.How to show the requirment tat i need.

```
$(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1900:+0',
            defaultDate: '01 JAN 1900'
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $('#dob-error').hide();
        });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU1xx.png)